# Printing or Private Use

Tags: self-publishing

I want to find a Print on Demand (POD) outfit that will print my book without an ISBN, as I do not want to sell my work through any outlet, print or electronic.  I just want copies to have and give to friends and family.  What do I do?

Comment: Are you set on a PoD service or would you be happy to branch out? I mean, some stationers will print and bind your work but I'm not sure if that comes under PoD.

Comment: How many copies do you want at a time? We had a small run of books printed very cheaply by just supplying a printer with a colour cover and the book as a Word file.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to print without an ISBN just because you don't want to pay for one? Or is there some reason why you really don't want to have an ISBN on the cover?

If the issue is the cost, then Create Space and Lulu will give you an ISBN for free, making that a moot point.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked in numerous printing companies and every single one of them would gladly print your book any way you want it.

ISBN's are not required by printers or authors (at least not if you are simply giving them away to friends and family); you'd simply supply your artwork/copy however you like.

If it's a small run (read: qty. of books produced) and a small page count (less than 100 pages), you could conceivably get Kinko's or the UPS Store to print and bind using Plastic Coil or Wire-O binding.

If it is a larger run (>500 books?) and/or a larger page count, you'd most likely need to go to a commercial printer for Stitch, Perfect or Case binding. Mind you, they'll also likely be able to do what you could get done at a retailer as mentioned above with better quality, but at a greater cost.

It may be beneficial to quote your project both ways: through a retail establishment **and** a commercial printer.

Hope that helps!